# Excel Count occupancies from cell to another cell

Tags: excel

I hope someone can assist me.

I have a spread sheet which has two tabs, the front tab is the summary, second data tab.

I am trying to workout a formula which will count Name A and how many time it occurs in the data tab?

**Example:**

```
NAME:         Count?
Andrew         4
Roger          2
Tony           2
Clive          1
Dean           1
```

**Data Tab:**

```
Account No.    Name
123            Andrew
221            Andrew
331            Andrew
133            Clive
341            Dean
091            Tony
001            Tony
999            Roger
123            Roger
112            Andrew
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy! Sheet 1: Column A contains the names you lookup in Data. Enter the formula in Sheet1>Column B.

```
=COUNTIF(Data!$B$1:$B$20;A1)
```